# Is it true that electrically assisted pedal cycles must be limited to 6mph if operating with twist throttles?

Tags: england-and-wales, traffic

What provision or instrument requires this, if so?

Comment: And why might this be true?

Comment: Because a dealer claimed it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. In order to not be treated as a motor vehicle, "twist and goes" must be capable of pedal operation and must not provide electrical assistance above 15.5 mph.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/electrically-assisted-pedal-cycles-eapcs/electrically-assisted-pedal-cycles-eapcs-in-great-britain-information-sheet